# Any approach to feeding table with a DATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The table has a DATE field.

```
Tbl_a
ID       DATE
```

I need to sometimes feed `DATE` with a specified date: i.e. `2015-6-12`. 
And sometimes the date is implied. i.e. `NOW()` or `NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY`.

Thing is, when feeding `NOW()`, there's no apostrophes to the field, as `NOW` is preserved for MySQL. 
While feeding specific dates, the apostrophes are needed.

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_a ('2015-06-12')
```

As opposed to

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_a (NOW())
```

Of course this can be solved awkwardly with a function that tests for the first character to be a number, to decide if to add apostrophe,

But is there a straight way to do that I am missing?

EDIT: 
for clarification: I am getting the values from another table. So the other table holds a string representing a date. 'NOW()' or '2015-06-12'. That value has to be fed to Tbl_a.

Comment: Did not understand your question, could you explain a bit on it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think you should use a prepared statement instead and always bind the date. In case of "today" you just use `date('Y-m-d')` in php instead of your variable. No quotes needed, no potential sql injection problem.

Comment: `NOW()` provides a timestamp (date & time) which is contrary to the example you gave. Maybe try `CURDATE()` instead.

Comment: Edited for clarification

Comment: You have NOW() stored as a string in the database? And by commas do you actually mean quotes or dashes?

Comment: Can you please post the `CREATE TABLE` statement? I bet you aren't using dates at all but just fitting random stuff into a VARCHAR. PHP code (since you tagged the question as PHP) won't hurt either.

Comment: before passing any values in the insert query, why don't you generate the current date and add it to a variable and pass that to the insert query. If the supplied value is not in the format YYYY-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

1 way you could solve your problem is to use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to check if the supplied date is really a date or not. strtotime will return FALSE or -1 (PHP <= 5.1.0) on failure

Example:

```
$date = [some_supplied_date];
if (!strtotime($date)) {
     $date = date('Y-m-d');
}

$sql = "Insert into tbl_a('$date')";
```

There's a bit of a problem with my code above you need to handle strings like now, +1 day, etc... since it will be a valid result when checked with strtotime

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help:

```
insert into Tbl_a (newdate)
  select 
     case dates
     WHEN 'now()' THEN now()
     else STR_TO_DATE(dates, '%y-%m/%d')
     END
  from Tbl_b;
```